# PL SQL Problem : PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type , and the paramters are of the same type

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a procedure that will loop comma separated string and will do update statement based on each value 
this is the table :

```
ID                        NUMBER
MOVEMENT_NUMBER           VARCHAR(150)
STATUS                    VARCHAR(500)
```

and this is the pl sql code

```
 PROCEDURE updateAutomotiveDeliveryStatus(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS IN varchar)
  is
  temp varchar2(500);
  BEGIN
 FOR temp IN
   (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
     FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, ',')+1
      )
      LOOP
      update hr.test1 te set te.status = 'completed'
      where status = temp ;
       --dbms_output.put_line(MOVEMENT_NUM.*);
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

but i keep get this error at the where condtion

[Error] PLS-00382 (28: 22): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is a **cursor**. You need to reference its attributes, in this case the aliased expression `l`.

The `temp` declared in the variable section is ignored, because it's out of scope. That is, the FOR ... LOOP construct defines a cursor, and code within the loop references the cursor, not any variable defined outside the cursor.

```
PROCEDURE updateAutomotiveDeliveryStatus(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS IN varchar)
  is
BEGIN
  FOR temp IN
    (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
     FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, ',')+1
     )
  LOOP
    update hr.test1 te 
    set te.status = 'completed'
    where status = temp.l ;
       --dbms_output.put_line(MOVEMENT_NUM.*);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

---

> but what does l mean

`l` is a column alias. We can't reference an expression like `trim(regexp_substr(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))` so we give it an alias which we can use in SQL or PL/SQL. Generally it's good practice to use a meaningful name, e.g. `movement_number`, to make the code more readable.

Comment: i've make it te.MOVEMENT_NUMBER = temp.1
but now i get error 
[Error] ORA-00933 (28: 93): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @osfar - it's `temp.l` with the letter L, not `temp.1` with the number one. That `l` is from the alias you gave to the column expression in your `select`.

Answer (score 1):

You posted too much code so I removed it.

As of the error you got: you can't set value to *cursor*, but *cursor variable* - `temp.l` in your case.

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test1 (status varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1
  2    select 'A' from dual union all
  3    select 'C' from dual union all
  4    select 'D' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * From test1;

STATUS
--------------------
A
C
D

SQL>
```

Procedure: note that variable you declared (line #4) isn't used at all, so - remove it. This `temp` is different from `temp` used in cursor `for` loop.

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  PROCEDURE updateAutomotiveDeliveryStatus(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS IN varchar)
  3    is
  4    -- temp varchar2(500); unnecessary; you don't do anything with it
  5  BEGIN
  6    FOR temp IN
  7     (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
  8       FROM dual
  9          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_MOVEMENT_NUMBERS, ',')+1
 10     )
 11     LOOP
 12       update test1 te set te.status = 'completed'
 13         where status = temp.l ;
 14     END LOOP;
 15  END;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec updateAutomotiveDeliveryStatus('A,B,C');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test1;

STATUS
--------------------
completed
completed
D

SQL>
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Didn't even notice it. Thank you, @Alex.